# Small change, big difference

Tags: word-choice

Is there a way of saying that a small change will make a big difference? The current sentence doesn't sound very good. I do not want to say something along the lines of a domino effect.

Comment: "That's one small step for a man..."

Comment: [Butterfly Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)

Comment: [Let's eat grandma!](http://www.gregor.co/uploads/1/4/2/3/14239340/677466885_orig.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say **pivotal** fits the bill nicely.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pivotal

> Extremely important and affecting how something develops.

- A pivotal moment in the history of the Egyptian state
- He played a pivotal role in the negotiations.
- A pivotal figure/player in US politics
- Pivotal to: He sees these reforms as pivotal to our economic interests in Asia.

From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pivot

> A pin, point, or short shaft on the end of which something rests and
>   turns, or upon and about which something rotates or oscillates.

Comment: +1 for pivotal. Reminds me 'cardinal', which online dictionaries define as 'of the greatest importance: fundamental' but which my ancient, paper dictionary defines as 'pertaining to a hinge'.

Comment: "Pivotal" is good (+1). A pivot is small by itself, but allows something much larger to change orientation, greatly magnifying its significance.

Answer (score 9):

This is nothing but the *[butterfly effect](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/butterfly-effect)*.

Comment: per definition: the idea that a very small change in one part of a system can have large effects in other parts. This seems to put an emphasis on the differentt parts which is not what I want.

Comment: Didn't see this answer when I commented above.  Either way, @Vader the butterfly effect doesn't imply changes in different systems but rather that, for example, a ball placed at the crest of a hill may roll into any surrounding valley depending on, among other things, slight differences in its initial position.  Shift the position very slightly and it may roll in a completely different direction.  The 'different part' is more of the fact that a small change creates a vastly different result.

Comment: I also think of the butterfly effect being about large **unpredictable** changes in other parts of a system.

Comment: The Butterfly Effect applies to systems meeting the definition of _chaotic_, such as the weather ("a butterfly flapping its wings over the Amazon causing a tornado in Texas, two weeks later"). I don't think it really applies to the situation described in the OP.

Answer (score 9):

The [avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) is signified by making a small change with a big difference in result.

> Usage:
>
> By changing one function in my code I caused an avalanche effect.  The
>   function caused a loop therefor taking down the entire website.

Also if a small change creates incremental changes that ends up being a big change, you could refer to that as the **snowball effect**.

Comment: can you please give an example in a sentence?

Comment: @Vader - added an example and its close cousin.

Comment: Upvoted for snowball actually, I've seen it used more than avalanche.

Answer (score 3):

A well known phrase for a small action having a wide sphere of influence (change) is the [ripple effect](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ripple+effect): a spreading effect or series of consequences caused by a single action or event. One small event spreads outwards involving more and more.

Think Rosa Parks: one woman who refused to give up her seat to a white man. She was arrested. It set off a widespread dissatisfaction, turned into indignation, the Montgomery Bus Boycott, gave a relatively unknown (Rev. Martin Luther King Jr.) a [Montgomery platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Parks#Montgomery_Bus_Boycott) which lead to a nationwide platform, and gave the entire Civil Rights movement a focus, an icon, and a needed boost.

> Parks' quiet yet outrageous act of civil disobedience was a stone dropped into a pool that would soon grow turbulent. Its [ripple effect](http://womensissues.about.com/b/2010/12/01/celebrating-rosa-parks-courageous-act-55-years-later.htm) led to significant changes in the social fabric of the United States over the next decade and ended segregation laws in the South.
>
> ...whatever your faith, you can believe in the spirit of strength, justice, and courage that prompted one small woman to take a big risk on a crowded bus on a December evening -- **a shining moment that changed the world for the better.** - *Rosa Parks in 1988* © Angel Franco, *New York Times*

Comment: To me, the ripple effect is just spreading without amplification.  I would prefer Mynamite's domino effect as a more natural candidate in your example.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - I have no problem with your preference of another answer, but I believe from your comment that we greatly disagree on the meaning of the ripple effect. It spreads outwards involving more and more people. Think Rosa Parks: one woman who refused to give up her seat to a white man. It set off a spreading dissatisfaction, turned into indignation, the Montgomery Bus Boycott, gave a relatively unknown (Rev. Martin Luther King Jr.) a Montgomery platform which lead to a nationwide platform, and gave the entire Civil Rights movement a focus and an icon. I think it is an apt metaphor.

Comment: I stand corrected by your new example.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - I'm glad you challenged me. It made my answer a better one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

**"Mighty oaks from little acorns grow"**

Answer (score 2):

Or the [domino effect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXtDChNB3gc) - one small push and everything changes.

Comment: If you'd read well you'd have seen that the original post mentioned that "domino effect" was not what it was after…

Comment: The domino effect leads to something happening far away in distance or time, but not necessarily of greater magnitude than the original push. It's the same size disturbance that travels a long way, rather than something that expands.

Comment: @user58319 Ah you're so right. By the time I'd read through all the answers I'd forgotten what the OP said.

Comment: @user58319 It's not Myna's fault - the question was edited after many of the answers came in to clarify what op was looking for.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Thank you! Glad to know I'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

This is something of a tangent but since two copper coins would surely count as "small change" then what Jesus was recorded as saying seems relevant ...

`As Jesus looked up, he saw the rich putting their gifts into the temple treasury. He also saw a poor widow put in two very small copper coins. ‘Truly I tell you,’ he said, ‘this poor widow has put in more than all the others. (Luke 21:1-3, NIV)`

This is commonly referred to as the "widow's mite" and suggests that even small change can be a valued contribution that makes a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

A more direct phrase may be something similar to, "...seemingly insignificant change..." I can't think of much else along those lines, though I'm sure others can.

Otherwise, a "single wave which became a tsunami" (though scientifically incorrect) or, "the spark that ignited an explosion"
"Every (vote, penny, other object?) counts" "feather that broke the camel's back"

The icing on the cake could be a small change that makes the whole much better if its worded right.

Something that is made a big deal of even though it is a small change might be made into a mountain from a molehill.

Answer (score 0):

A direct analog to the domino effect would be **cascade**.

It is used with this exact meaning, for example, [in chemistry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cascade) and [Database design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE).